# How can I get the page title in WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, browser, windows-phone-7.1

How can I get the page title in a WebBrowser control when I navigate to different websites?

---

xmlns

```
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
```

Properties starting with D

```
DataContext
DesiredSize
Dispatcher
DoubleTap
```

xaml tag

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="browser" Height="760" VerticalAlignment="Top"></phone:WebBrowser>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem. @Akash Kava's answer is almost correct but this is the correct javascript to read the html title:

```
String title = (string)browser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.title.toString()");
```

Comment: As David said, to work properly this must be called in the **WebBrowser.LoadCompleted** event handler. In addition, since this is being executed in an event handler, the above code should be called within the action of either `Control.Invoke` for WPF or `Dispatcher.Invoke` for Silverlight/Windows Phone if the UI is being updated.

Answer (score 2):

For me the following code works. The answers from @Akash and @Mikko set me on the right path, but I still had some problems with a few websites. The problem as I understand it is that the Navigated event is raised when the `WebBrowser` component starts getting data from the remote server. As such the DOM object is not yet complete, so calling the `document.title` throws an error. So I just retry after a few milliseconds till I get the title. This "loop" has never iterated more than 3 times on any website I tested and flawlessly brought me the title every time.

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(UpdateText);
}

private void UpdateText(object o)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            textBlock1.Text = webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.title").ToString();
        }
        catch (SystemException)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(UpdateText);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that

```
String title = browser.Document.Title;
```

should do the trick.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.title.aspx).

Comment: Properties starting with D: DataContext, DesiredSize, Dispatcher, DoubleTap. (Microsoft.Phone.Controls). xaml tag: `<phone:WebBrowser Name="browser" Height="760" VerticalAlignment="Top"></phone:WebBrowser>`

Comment: Sorry, was thinking of the regular Forms WebBrowser control. Have you tried @Akash Kava's answer but with the `IsScriptEnabled` property set to `true`?

Answer (score 1):

All answers are not 100% correct:

You must call the following:

String title = (string)browser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.title.toString()");

in the **LoadCompleted** event of the browser, and not in the **navigated** event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402855%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to get title as,

```
 String title = browser.InvokeScript("document.title");
```

I don't know it's correct or not but you can try window.title too.

Comment: I tried on `LoadCompleted` event and it thrown an unknown exception.

Comment: You must enable scripting as per msdn documentation and also this method can only be called after document was loaded so you must wait for sometime if document is not ready.

Comment: I tried calling this when receiving the Navigated event and get an exception that reads "Error: 80020006". And yes, I have IsScriptEnabled="True" in my XAML.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me, note the navigated event, if you use loaded it will trigger just before the page is loaded, you want that to trigger sometime "after" the page is Fully Loaded, navigated acts as that event.

```
private void web1_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //Added thread using "using System.Thread", to act as a buffer for any page delay.
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        String title = (string)web1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.title");
        PageTitle.Text = title;

    }
```