# Type text inside textbox from a website inside the webBrowser using windws phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Trying to type text inside a textbox on a certin website that i load from the webBrowser.

Tried using HTMLElement but it's not recognized cause it's from system.windows.FORMS.

any ideas on how i might solve this problem?

example:

```
browser.Navigate(new URI("http://www.google.com"));
// Here get the textbox that we all type our text to search (the search textbox)
//type text inside it.
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to invoke some javascript. E.g. to get title:

[How can I get the page title in WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699381/how-can-i-get-the-page-title-in-webbrowser-control)

So, browser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementById('inputbox').text = 'INPUT'");

(javascript not tested).

Comment: Boland, I'am trying to get the textbow so i can type in it HTMLPage is not referenced  in windows phone, or maybe i'm missing a .*dll?

Comment: Hmm, I just see it is indeed other namespace. See my editted post.